# Why does Wolfram|Alpha give a different answer for the derivative of the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

Consider the function $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2}$. To find $f'(x)$, I use the rule $\color{red}{\boxed{\color{black}{\large\big(\sqrt[n]{u^m}\big)'=\frac{mu'}{n\sqrt[n]{u^{n-m}}}}}}$. Therefore $\boxed{\large f'(x)=\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}}$. But [Wolfram|Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) says a different thing. See [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative%20of%203th%20root%20of%20x%5E2). It says that the derivative is $\large\frac{2x}{3(x^2)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$ which is a different thing. Also, it states that the derivative is $\large\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$ **assuming $\boldsymbol{x>0}$** while we know that this is incorrect, because the derivative is $\large\frac{2}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$ but **for all $\boldsymbol x$ in reals**, and not assuming $x>0$. What's the problem?

Comment: Worse than that the same result is performed if  "Assuming
"root"
is the real-valued root".

Comment: What is your problem, I do not see any problems with the formulas provided by Wolfram|Alpha or Mathematica.

Comment: @azerbajdjan: Don't you find  the result of `Series[D[(x^2)^(1/3), x], {x, 0, 5}]` which is `(2 x^(4/3))/(3 (x^2)^(2/3) x^(1/3))+O[x]^(16/3)` strange?

Comment: It's using the principal valued cube root, e.g. $(-1)^{1/3} = 1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$. Try it yourself, if you cube that complex number you get $-1$.

Comment: Questions about Wolfram|Alpha are explicitly off-topic here, although it appears from the comments and answers that this is really a *math* question.

Answer (score 3):

```
D[CubeRoot[x^2], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[x > 0, Simplify[%]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At Wolfram alpha, you asked for cubic root of x^2, which is for x>0. It said **Assuming root is the principal root**

```
 Reduce[CubeRoot[x^2] == (x)^(2/3)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Hence

```
 D[(x)^(2/3),x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, this site is really for questions about Wolfram Mathematica, not Wolfram alpha. These two language are not exactly the same even though they both start with the name Wolfram.

Comment: Worse than that the same result is performed if "Assuming "root" is the real-valued root".

Answer (score 1):

W|A and Mathematica agree here. Note that these two functions are not the same; the input in the question is `f1[x]`.

```
f1[x_] := (x^2)^(1/3)
f2[x_] := (x^(1/3))^2
```

So the derivatives do not agree. Both are correct though.

```
{D[f1[x], x], D[f2[x], x]}

(* Out[256]= {(2 x)/(3 (x^2)^(2/3)), 2/(3 x^(1/3))} *)
```

(I'll make this a Community wiki and also vote to close since it reduces to a misunderstanding of the definition, not to mention off-topic if W|A is the issue.)